# Unable to transfer tokens from another contract

Tags: solidity, crowdsale

I am learning soildity.

I created a fixed supply token. My token supply is 1000000 with 0 decimal places. Now, I want to transfer tokens from using new contract, so I created a new contract named Crowdsale. Whenever I am transfring the token from crowdsale contract it gives an error.

"transact to Crowdsale.(fallback) errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.  Debug the transaction to get more information. "

Note: I am passing the token owner address to the Crowdsale contract at the time of deploying.

you can find my contract using below link:

https://github.com/maksa14/Contracts/blob/master/Test/TokenCrowdsale.sol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address that you need to pass is the `token contract` address not the address of the owner. This doesn't show an error when you do it. However, your code has some issues:

This function:

```
function transferToken (address _to, uint256 _tokenAmount) public returns (bool) {
        return token.transfer(_to,_tokenAmount);
    }
```

will trigger the transfer function in `token` but the msg.sender here is not who originate the transaction. msg.sender here is the `crowdsale`contract address, which doesn't have any tokens and the function will always return false.

You can transfer all the tokens to `crowdsale` contract first, so that it can sell it to the users.

Hope this helps